# Failed to install 'plugin.google.maps':Error: Variable(s) missing: API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic project it works fine, but when I try to run this

```
ionic platform add android
```

I get this error :

```
Failed to install 'plugin.google.maps':Error: Variable(s) missing: API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID
    at C:\Users\RSone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:
299:23
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\RSone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\RSone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:8
16:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\RSone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\
q.js:749:13)
    at C:\Users\RSone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\RSone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I got same error while installing Google Map plugin. I installed it by phonegap method rather then cordova way.

First if you have tried installing plugin. Check it in plugin list. I don't kow in ionic, but in cordova its

```
cordova plugin ls
```

If Google maps plugin is installed then uninstall it.

Now Download Folder as given there.[Google Map Plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/archive/master.zip)

Extract and edit API Keys in plugin.xml (Refer https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Phonegap-Usage#5-install-this-plugin)

later Install it using local plugin -

`cordova local plugin add (path to the plugin)/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin-master/`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by removing and reinstall cordova-plugin-googlemaps:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-googlemaps
```

and then

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

Answer (score 0):

To install this plugin on PhoneGap, you need to prepare your API keys for both Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps iOS SDK.
Inustrctuions how to do it are here: https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Phonegap-Usage

Comment: Am in this step **5.Install this plugin** i not able to find the file `plugin.xml`